# Locked question on the hot questions list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions, locked-questions

The following question has been on the hot questions list for what seems like awhile:

[What does “covfefe” exactly mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/391945/142967)

It's also currently locked. Shouldn't this disqualify it from the hot questions list?